# Iterate connected nodes in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I need to get the nodes connected to a given node, and highlight them. The "components" function looks good for this, however my traversal fails. The component collection shows a size of one and only the original node gets highlighted.

```
cynode = cy.getElementById(idstr);
comps = cynode.components();    
for (i = 0; i < comps.length; i++) /* really there's only one component */
{
    comp = comps[i];
    alert(comp.size());   /* this always returns 1!! */
    comp.nodes().addClass('nodehlt');  /* only the original node gets highlighted */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

eles.components() : Get the connected components, considering only the elements in the calling collection. An array of collections is returned, with each collection representing a component.

If the set of elements you consider is only a single node, there can only ever be one component.

You need to get the components of the whole graph (`cy.elements.components()`) -- or of the subgraph you're interested in.  Of those components, you then need to find the one that contains the node of interest.

Comment: Great, thanks. My confusion was that I thought it would be returning the components connected to the elements of the calling set.

Comment: Pretty much all of the API is structured so you can make queries that consider only a particular subgraph -- the calling collection.  If the function worked the way you described, you'd have to remove elements from the graph to do subgraph queries.

Comment: cy.elements().components()